# Combine data of two columns in power bi and combine set for new table

Tags: datatables, powerbi, unique, selection, lookup

I have two tables:

Table #1 - `recipe`:

[image]

Table #2 - `cakes`:

[image]

What I want in PowerBI is:

1. select material (done)
2. show table with all the recipes versions
3. show another table with all the cakes baked based on recipe (and previous versions)

So far so good, I've create a custom table with material, cakematerial and recipematerial.

[image]

Now I also would like to have another report/table showing orders with the same lot and order-prefix.

For example: Ordernr 2000-010 and ordernr 2000-020 have the same LOT (lt011c). I want these to be shown in one table and then another table with the recipes (and history) belonging to both orders.

So in this case: Recipenr L10-BACK01 and L11-BACK01 with complete version history.

Is that possible?

Datamodel in Power BI:

[image: Datamodel]

Comment: Could you include an image of the data model in power bi?  As long as the tables have relationships to each other, you should be able to show anything in a table and filter other results on that.  I'm not clear on where you're stuck

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply.
There is no relation between the order-prefix and lot nr.  I've uploaded an image of the datamodel. I'm stuck on the part that when I select an order (right) that I want to use that selected order for input based on the lot and order prefix (orderprefix = order minus last 4 characters.

Comment: I think you may just need to change the relationships to `both` directions between the 3 tables.  This would allow you to filter from any table related to `Material`

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz 
Sometimes the solution is so simple. Thank you for your input. I'm able to get the results as wanted. Can I give you points for this?!?

Comment: Hey, no problem.  glad to help.  I replied with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to change the relationships to `both` directions between the 3 tables. This would allow you to filter from any table related to `Material`